# Ubuntu 22.04 How to disable two finger scrolling completely

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 22.04, synaptics, multi-touch

I am really struggling with Ubuntu22.04 upgrade and my synaptics touchpad on Acer Aspire E15 (E5-574G-54Y2) laptop. Everything was working just great before the 22.04 upgrade but now, the touchpad seems to be out of touch with its Ubuntu settings (no pun intended)! In all applications that I use on a regular basis (Chrome Browser, Thunderbird, File Manager, Libre Office...) the cursor continues to jiggle and scroll up or down by a few centimeters (really bad when I am selecting a list item) making the selection change automatically. I have installed and removed synaptics touchpad package but with no difference. I have also tried enabling disabling smooth scroll settings, disabled two finger scrolling but to no effect.

At this stage, I think it is all related to two finger scrolling that I have disabled but continues to be in effect across all applications. I suspect that the settings are extra sensitive and therefore even my single finger movements are being interpreted as two finger scroll and thus making the cursor scroll up or down.

Any suggestions? Is there a way for me to completely disable two finger scrolling across ALL applications on Ubuntu 22.04? The experience is exceptionally bad when trying to use Google Maps in Chrome browser - the map automatically zooms in and out with slightest of cursor movement (no pinch/zoom needed!).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to 22.04 LTS: Two-finger scrolling always worked despite the switch in GUI settings.

For a start, check Synaptics touchpad setting via cli: `synclient -l | grep TwoFingerScroll`. In my case it was:

```
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
```

Then disable Vertical Two-finger Scrolling: `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0`.

To make this setting permanent, add the following line to the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-my-synaptics.conf`:

```
Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "0"
```